# Correct json Path

Tags: java, jsonpath

Please help me with correct json path. I am trying to extract "500" from "value".

Json (part of it) looks like this:

```
Vehicle {
"code": "BCA",
"name": "COLL",
"description": "Collision",
"limitTerms": [],
"deductibleTerms": [
{
"code": "qsw",
"name": "",
"value": "500",
"valueCode": "",
"valueDescription": "",
}
],
"otherTerms": [],
},
```

I want to use the name or description than reach to deductibleTerms and extract value from it.

I tried wrtting json path like that (which is for sure wrong)

"$.vehicle[description='Collision' and .deductibleTerms[*].value]"

Comment: @yshavit The `$.` is a [JsonPath expression](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) (similar to an XPath for XML).

Comment: @Andreas Ah, so that's an actual string literal being passed into some library call? Gotcha, thanks. Reverted my edit.

Comment: This isn't really a [tag:java] question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.deductibleTerms[*].value` should not be inside the filter `[]` part of the expression since you are not filtering on it.

`$.vehicle[description='Collision'].deductibleTerms[*].value`